# Celery worker introspection to obtain hostname/nodename

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to run py.test integration tests for my Django 1.8 application with
a full Celery 3.1 setup, that is, with a real queue (not CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER).

To do that, I need to convince the worker to use my server-based test DB (PostgreSQL) rather than the standard configured DB (SQlite3, which cannot talk to a second process).

To do that, I want to simply modify the [DATABASES setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases) in the worker process before the database is first used. (I want to keep SQlite for the other py.test tests as well as the normal non-test DB for interactive testing.)

To do that, the worker needs to recognize that it is running in test mode as opposed to 'normal' mode.
To indicate test mode, I start the worker with different node names:

```
celery worker -A myapp --concurrency=1 -n myworker --loglevel=info
```

for normal mode versus

```
celery worker -A myapp --concurrency=1 -n mytestworker --loglevel=info
```

for test mode.

**Question**: How can the celery.py module in my Django application read
out the nodename (hostname, as set with the `-n` option) of the worker?

There appear to be three processes involved (I have no further
configuration for concurrency beyond the above `=1`):

1. The `celery.exe` (I am on Windows),
2. the *worker* itself, and
3. the single *worker process* (which is the relevant one for me).

Is this correct?

There appear to be different [signals](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) that celery sends to each process:

1. `celeryd_init` is sent to `celery.exe`,
2. `worker_init` is sent to the *worker*,
3. `worker_process_init` is sent to the *worker process*

Is this correct, too?

I added the following to `celery.py` in my Django application:

```python
import celery.signals

def init_here(signal, sender):
    print("call %s(sender=%s)" % (signal, sender))

@celery.signals.celeryd_init.connect
def celeryd_init(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    init_here("celeryd_init", sender)

@celery.signals.worker_init.connect
def worker_init(sender, **kwargs):
    init_here("worker_init", sender)

@celery.signals.worker_process_init.connect
def worker_process_init(sender, **kwargs):
    init_here("worker_process_init", sender)
```

When I start the worker in test mode as indicated above, I get the following output (among other things):

```
call celeryd_init(sender=celery@mytestworker)
call worker_init(sender=celery@mytestworker)
[2015-09-30 15:53:23,767: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@mytestworker ready.
[2015-09-30 15:53:24,282: WARNING/Worker-1] call worker_process_init(sender=None)
```

Too bad! The relevant process `Worker-1` does not receive the relevant information `celery@mytestworker`.
How can it obtain the hostname?

Comment: My above problem is indeed (as suggested by @Louis) best solved by an environment variable. However, I would still like to know the answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can get it to work, I do not recommend using worker names to detect whether you are in test mode or not. It would be a hack.

The way I've solved the issue of knowing whether my code is running in test mode or not is to have a different settings file called `proj/test_settings.py` (whereas the "regular" one is at `proj/settings.py`), where `proj` is my project's name (same with `PROJ` below). I have it create a setting that determines whether we are in testing mode or not:

```
from .settings import *

PROJ_TESTING = True
```

This variable is set to true only by the `test_settings` file. Note that it is possible to also have in this `test_settings.py` file some lines that override the default values set in `settings.py`. For instance, I do have code there that changes the database configuration, and logging.

I arrange the code that launches tests to set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=proj.test_settings`. Since my celery workers used in testing are launched by the code that runs my test, then they are loading the test settings and running with `PROJ_TESTING` true. So to check for testing mode if I need to, I can do this:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.PROJ_TESTING:
  # Do what we need when we are testing.
else:
  # Do something else.
```

This method of doing things mirrors how we set the debug mode by setting the `DEBUG` setting to `True`.